# Python: Is it possible for an object to change itself to something else?

Tags: python, pointers, reference

```
class Myclass(object):
    def get_val(self):
        return 100

my_obj = MyClass()
data = {
    'key_1': my_obj,
    ...  # other fields
}
```

Later I need to change the object to it's value, I could only iterate the dictionary like this, maybe recursively:

```
for key in data:
    if type(data[key]) is MyClass:
        data[key] = data[key].get_val()
```

But is it possible to do this via my_obj itself?

I don't think so because in python you cannot manipulate pointers like you can do in c, but is there any better ways?

Comment: the object cannot do that itself, although a subclass of dictionary can override how it handles the `data[key]` lookup fairly easily.

Comment: As already said, there is a variaty of magic methods you can override in your class to return a certain value

Comment: Why do you need to do this in the first place?

Answer (score 0):

Objects cannot replace any/all references of themselves with something else. Period.

However if you need to have a dictionary of pointer objects (have some form of `.get()` method to return the actual data) then just overriding the `__getitem__` method of a `dict` subclass will let you add in the appropriate logic when retrieving data from the dictionary:

```
class MyDict(dict):
    def __getitem__(self,item):
        value = dict.__getitem__(self,item) #may raise error
        if isinstance(value, Myclass):
            return value.get_val()
        else:
            return value

my_obj = Myclass()

data = MyDict({
    'key_1': my_obj,
     # other fields
})

assert data["key_1"] == 100
```

Although note that this only changes that one method of lookup, using `.items()` or `.get()` etc. will not use the modified `__getitem__` so a more complete implementation could be done with `collections.MutableMapping`:

```
import collections

class MyDict(collections.MutableMapping):
    __slots__ = ["raw_dict"]
    def __init__(self,*args,**kw):
        self.raw_dict = dict(*args,**kw)

    def __getitem__(self,item):
        value = self.raw_dict[item]
        if isinstance(value, Myclass):
            return value.get_val()
        return value

    def __setitem__(self,item, value):
        self.raw_dict[item] = value
    def __delitem__(self, item):
        del self.raw_dict[item]
    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.raw_dict)
    def __iter__(self):
        return iter(self.raw_dict)
```

Then all the other methods like `.get` and `.pop` and `.items` etc. are all created from the ones defined here.   And the original pointer objects are still accessible via `data.raw_dict["key_1"]` so nothing is hidden/lost track of.